# Use different versions of packages in R

Tags: r, version-control, package, checkpoint

I am reading a book published in 2019 that uses a package (*JWileymisc*) that has been updated and some of the functions are deprecated, so I am spending too much time trying to update the examples. The authors use *checkpoint* package but I have not been able to make it work in my laptop (I don't have full rights and could not install *R version 3.5.1*).
I installed the older version of the package it is used in the book but I still get error message saying the functions could not be found. Is there a way around it without *checkpoint* and this old version of R? Or is it possible to call a function from an old version of a package? I am using Windows, by the way.
Thanks! :)

Comment: One way, is that if you know Git (or are willing to learn some of the basics) you could clone the repository and install a previous version. Here is the repo: `https://github.com/JWiley/JWileymisc`

Comment: Thanks @sindri_baldur for the tip, I had installed the old version of the package via `devtools::install_version("JWileymisc", version = "0.3.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`. I see now in gitthub someone else ran into the same problem a couple of days ago and JWiley already answered: https://github.com/JWiley/JWileymisc/issues/5